# What are the best practices to display tables on mobile? (Web development)

Tags: mobile, html-table

I have to redesign a website that relies heavily on tables and I can't find a good way to display them, I'm mostly interested in displaying the tables correctly on Blackberry, iPhone and Android.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by 'Good way to display them'.
Do you mean the tables are too wide for the screen ?

iPhone & Android use webkit which have excellent table support. Recent Blackberry's also have great table support. Displaying html tables shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: yes I mean that some tables are too wide in the sense that the user has to drag the screen to the left or right (or down) to watch the values and the headers remain on top that seems a bit annoying

Comment: Unfortunately the only real option is to cutdown the amount of data in the tables i think.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar problem.  I'm leaning mostly toward converting the table from "horizontal records" into "vertical records".  Maybe I'll also give the user the option to select which of the available fields to display and then show/hide those fields accordingly.  I'm torn between two different types of "vertical record".  The first is a table with two columns, but that only works if what used to be a header doesn't wrap to multiple lines because of the narrower width on a phone.  The second type is a header in bold on one line and then the data for that "column" on the next line but slightly indented.  The problem with the second type is it gets to be a lot of vertical scrolling and wasted space but it can accommodate longer header titles and record data.

I really don't think there is a win-win option here.  The smaller screen size really demands less content.  We can't just take a real table of information built for desktop browsers and expect to transform it in a universal way for a mobile user.